# Importing modules without overriding each other

Tags: python

I'm a bit confused on how to properly structure this. I know there has to be a solution otherwise people would be having module conflicts all the time. Let me explain.

I've written two separate tools using Python for an application called Maya. The tool structures are similar, each tool having a helper py filed called **actions.py**. When I import them, the last imported module overwrites the first one's **actions**.

**ToolA**

```
.../ToolA (root folder in python path)
   - __init__.py (empty)
   - actions.py (functions)
   - main.py
```

in `main.py` i import actions `from ToolA import actions`

**ToolB**

```
.../ToolB (root folder in python path)
   - __init__.py (empty)
   - actions.py (functions)
   - main.py
```

in `main.py` i import actions `from ToolB import actions`

How can I make the actions local to the file it's being imported to, in order to avoid conflicts. When i look at modules like numpy on github. It contains .py files with names similar to ones i use in my tools. I never have conflicts in those cases.

It's worth noting that both tools are executed in the same environment. Running both of them at the same time.

**Override Explained....**

If i put a print statement in each of the tools `print(actions)` i noticed that if i launch ToolA it prints that path `...ToolA/actions.py`

When i launch ToolB while ToolA remains open and it prints `...ToolB/actions.py`

However if i click on the button in ToolA dialog it prints the `...ToolB/actions.py` not longer pointing to it's own actions.py file.

Comment: `from ToolA import actions as actionsA; from ToolB import actions as actionsB`

Comment: Or just `import toolA.actions; import toolB.actions`, and use qualified names (`toolA.actions.whatever` instead of `actions.whatever`).

Comment: "When I import them, the last imported module overwrites the first one's actions." What does this mean? Where does the "overwriting" appear to take place? What observable behaviour occurs that should not occur? Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - if the problem is indeed simply with how importing works, then Maya shouldn't be necessary to reproduce the problem. But simply as described, there is no problem, because there is no "last imported module" issue, because only one module is being imported.

Comment: If there is some greater context in which, for example, `ToolA.main` and `ToolB.main` are both being imported, you need to *show that*.

Comment: Yeah it's worth noting that both tools are executed in the same environment. Running both of them at the same time.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel added info about the overriding issue

Comment: That doesn't help in the slightest. What does 'launching' a tool mean? It sounds like you are observing some results in a GUI provided by Maya, which is dynamically importing your code. Correct? Then, *what does the Maya documentation say* about such name conflicts?

Comment: you are correct. i dont see anything in the docs specifically regarding these conflicts that is why im searching for help online.

Answer (score 0):

Use `as` to change the name of modules to avoid conflict.

`from ToolA import actions as actionsA`

`from ToolB import actions as actionsB`

Comment: Is that the ideal approach for this? How do all these python modules manage this to avoid conflict. I would guess there would be thousands of naming conflicts, i can't imagine that ever module like numpy and whatnot do unique images to avoid conflicts.